# jQuery DataTable Date Range Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've tried to add a date range search for the jQuery DataTable.  The date range filter works fine and the normal Search over all Columns/Rows is also working.

My Problem is at the moment that the refresh of the table (Event) executes only after the Change in the normal search. So i need a Event which repaints / redraws / updates the Table.

So I need a call for something like a refresh at the datatable.

Here is my current code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            var table = $('#MainContent_gridClaim').dataTable();
        } catch (Err) { };
    });

    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
};


$.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.push(function (settings, data, indx) {
    //Min Max Document
    var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
    if (min === "" || max === "") {
        return true;
    }

    //Res Min Max
    var resMin = min.split(".");
    var resMax = max.split(".");

    //Min Max Date
    var dMin = new Date(resMin[2],resMin[1],resMin[0],0,0,0,0);
    var dMax = new Date(resMax[2],resMax[1],resMax[0],0,0,0,0);

    var resData = data[5].split(".");
    var resYear = resData[2].split(" ");
    var dJet = new Date(resYear[0], resData[1], resData[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var minSec = dMin.getTime();
    var maxSec = dMax.getTime();
    var actualSec = dJet.getTime();

    if (minSec<=actualSec&&actualSec<=maxSec) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call

```
$('#MainContent_gridClaim').dataTable().draw();
```

when you change the date range. I don't know your date picker plug-in, but you need to add `dataTable.draw()` call to something like `onChange` of the datepicker.

There is a similar example https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: it doesn't work. I have created the Table which references to the Datatable.JS with ASP.NET C#! Is this maybe a Problem, that i can not Access this stuff.